# Jmeter Simple controller and Transaction controller

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have one doubt regarding Simple and Transaction controller

MY Process is -> Goto Url -> Sign_in -> Create order

I recorded the script

Thread Group

My_page(Simple Controller)

api 1
api2
api3 (fails)

Page_Sigin_in(Simple Controller)

api1
api2
api3
api4

etc

like this am having in my jmx file

and i run the script in NON-GUI mode and created the dashboard Result

I open the index.html file -> view the result

Result is show for each single API

so it is hard to identify  each module api

if single api fails it will show it separately

so i used Transaction Controller , it will consolidate the Api and gives the result for each controller,

but if single api fails it's not showing the error result in dashboard

Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Simple Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) is basically a **container** for nested requests for logically grouping
- [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) can act in 2 modes:

  1. Response time for each request **plus** cumulative time of all nested requests (if `Generate parent sample` box is not checked)
  2. **Only** cumulative time of nested requests (if `Generate parent sample` box is checked)

So make sure that `Generate parent sample` box is not ticked and you should have consistent behavior for both scenarios.

More information: [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)